# Text jumps up before the algorithm (algorithm2e)

Tags: latex

Let's say i have a .tex file containing:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Section1}

    \subsection{SubSection1}
    Text Before:\newline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem ex, rhoncus id mattis sit amet, vehicula sed magna. Sed lacus libero, cursus ac mi at, ornare mattis orci. Sed aliquet felis non scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas congue volutpat neque sit amet placerat. Sed ultricies magna urna, nec egestas quam accumsan in. Nulla finibus quam dolor, at aliquet mauris tristique a. Aenean ultrices fermentum ante, a dignissim libero vehicula ac. Aenean ornare ullamcorper molestie. Nunc sagittis risus dolor, auctor sodales quam vestibulum a. Morbi tincidunt auctor odio. Sed feugiat diam nulla, commodo tincidunt lectus euismod vel. Aliquam quis maximus nunc, at cursus lectus. Vestibulum posuere aliquam diam, in malesuada nisi tincidunt id. Curabitur aliquam sapien cursus vestibulum tempor. Cras malesuada aliquet sapien et aliquet. Aliquam nibh metus, cursus at pharetra sit amet, tincidunt tincidunt ante. 

    \subsection{Subsection2}
    %Algorithm
    \SetKwFor{Loop}{Loop}{}{end}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Return{V}\;
    \caption{{\sc someAlgorithm.}}
    \label{algo:Algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}

    Text After:\newline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem ex, rhoncus id mattis sit amet, vehicula sed magna. Sed lacus libero, cursus ac mi at, ornare mattis orci. Sed aliquet felis non scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas congue volutpat neque sit amet placerat. Sed ultricies magna urna, nec egestas quam accumsan in. Nulla finibus quam dolor, at aliquet mauris tristique a. Aenean ultrices fermentum ante, a dignissim libero vehicula ac. Aenean ornare ullamcorper molestie. Nunc sagittis risus dolor, auctor sodales quam vestibulum a. Morbi tincidunt auctor odio. Sed feugiat diam nulla, commodo tincidunt lectus euismod vel. Aliquam quis maximus nunc, at cursus lectus. Vestibulum posuere aliquam diam, in malesuada nisi tincidunt id. Curabitur aliquam sapien cursus vestibulum tempor. Cras malesuada aliquet sapien et aliquet. Aliquam nibh metus, cursus at pharetra sit amet, tincidunt tincidunt ante.

\end{document}
```

i get the results as shown here: 
[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxwDi.jpg)
[Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNSF.jpg)

The text from section 2 should appear after the algorithm, yet, it appears on top of it, i don't know if it's a bug from algorithm2e, or it's me that is doing a mistake i can't spot. By the way, this happens with reference also, everytime the algorithm takes more space then remaining on current page, the thing that comes after it goes above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default `algorithm` is a floating environment, like figures or tables. This means that tex will try to find the best possible place for it. If you think you can do this better, you can force it to be put at the exactly the location it is in the text by adding the option `H` to the `algorithm` environment:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Section1}

    \subsection{SubSection1}
    Text Before:\newline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem ex, rhoncus id mattis sit amet, vehicula sed magna. Sed lacus libero, cursus ac mi at, ornare mattis orci. Sed aliquet felis non scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas congue volutpat neque sit amet placerat. Sed ultricies magna urna, nec egestas quam accumsan in. Nulla finibus quam dolor, at aliquet mauris tristique a. Aenean ultrices fermentum ante, a dignissim libero vehicula ac. Aenean ornare ullamcorper molestie. Nunc sagittis risus dolor, auctor sodales quam vestibulum a. Morbi tincidunt auctor odio. Sed feugiat diam nulla, commodo tincidunt lectus euismod vel. Aliquam quis maximus nunc, at cursus lectus. Vestibulum posuere aliquam diam, in malesuada nisi tincidunt id. Curabitur aliquam sapien cursus vestibulum tempor. Cras malesuada aliquet sapien et aliquet. Aliquam nibh metus, cursus at pharetra sit amet, tincidunt tincidunt ante. 

    \subsection{Subsection2}
    %Algorithm
    \SetKwFor{Loop}{Loop}{}{end}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Loop{$\infty$:}{
        $i++$\;
    }
    \Return{V}\;
    \caption{{\sc someAlgorithm.}}
    \label{algo:Algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}

    Text After:\newline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem ex, rhoncus id mattis sit amet, vehicula sed magna. Sed lacus libero, cursus ac mi at, ornare mattis orci. Sed aliquet felis non scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas congue volutpat neque sit amet placerat. Sed ultricies magna urna, nec egestas quam accumsan in. Nulla finibus quam dolor, at aliquet mauris tristique a. Aenean ultrices fermentum ante, a dignissim libero vehicula ac. Aenean ornare ullamcorper molestie. Nunc sagittis risus dolor, auctor sodales quam vestibulum a. Morbi tincidunt auctor odio. Sed feugiat diam nulla, commodo tincidunt lectus euismod vel. Aliquam quis maximus nunc, at cursus lectus. Vestibulum posuere aliquam diam, in malesuada nisi tincidunt id. Curabitur aliquam sapien cursus vestibulum tempor. Cras malesuada aliquet sapien et aliquet. Aliquam nibh metus, cursus at pharetra sit amet, tincidunt tincidunt ante.

\end{document}
```